# Rollerblading on shabbas?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, vehicles-transportation, kavod, makeh-befatish

What's the halachic problems if any to rollerblade on shabbas? Do we compare it to biking (Kaf Hachaim assurs it)? Are there any contemporary tshuvos which discuss this? I have heard two problems if they break one might come to fix the wheel, and that it is not bederch kavod shabbas.

Comment: Some links from googling: [Reportedly a p'sak from R' Moshe Feinstein](http://www.ottmall.com/mj_ht_arch/v9/mj_v9i79.html#CRT), [from R' Scheinberg](http://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/72/Q1/), from the [Aish HaTorah "Ask the Rabbi"](http://www.aish.com/atr/Rollerblading_on_Shabbat.html), and from [an unnamed rabbi](http://www.ottmall.com/mj_ht_arch/v51/mj_v51i55.html#CPB).

Comment: Regarding roller skates, Sh'miras Shabbos K'hilchasa (16:17) writes that in places where it is customary to forbid using skates on Shabbos, one should not be lenient. [WaPo claims](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2005/10/28/AR2005102801780.html) that Rabbi [Levi Yitzchak Halperin](http://www.scienceandhalacha.org/science.shtml) permits roller skates.

Comment: "I DON'T ROLL ON SHABBAS" - Walter Sobchak

Answer (score 2):

I found the [Rivevos Ephraim 3:206](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1085&pgnum=121) who addresses this issue. He says that in a Reshus harabim it is forbidden. He also mentions we don't ride bikes and this is similar. He references Shmiras shabbas khilchita 15:13.

He ends off saying that his wife claims that it should be forbidden because of digging up dirt and uprooting grass. He says that even if there is no grass or dirt it is forbidden.

Comment: @DoubleAA , wow your fast

Answer (score 0):

Hacham Bension Musafi Shalti"a says that without an Eruv it is forsure Asur, but with an Eruv it is okay for kids until age 9. (He adds to make sure there are no lights). But it seems like he would Matir for an adult Bimkom Miswa (see answers 37054 and 13421 on doresh-tzion.co.il)

Comment: Without eiruv what's the problem he mentions?

Comment: What is Miswa? Do you mean Mitzvah?

Comment: The issue without an Eruv i presume would be carrying. @Ariel the minhag in my family is to say Miswa.

Comment: Interesting. I've heard people say Mitzwah, but not Miswa (or Misva). Is there a recording I could hear of how you say it?

Comment: http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xbage0_le-chema-yissrael_webcam#.UUeRCD8l1DE Keriat Shema in the way I pronounce it.

Comment: I hear 'Metzawecha hayom', not 'Mesawecha hayom' in your video. But I hear "Miswotai asher'. Thanks.

Comment: OK, now I don't understand. Two words later "anochi metzawe". What decides if it's a 'tz' or an 's' sound?

Comment: @Ariel there is no difference. I'm not exactly sure why he switches but the Yeshiva he represents all say "S".

Comment: Most Sephardim used to pronounce the "vav" the right way which is wow, and the sSadi the same way.the samaech is pronounced with the tongue on the bottom part of the teeth and the sSadi is pronounced with the tongue on the upper teeth exhaling.

Comment: @Ariel, the letter Tzadi is cognate to the Arabic letter Sod. Try out Google Translate to look up how to say "friend" in Arabic (Saddiq, cognate to Hebrew "Tzaddik"), and play the audio. It's not a true 's', but like DhoweedYaAgov describes above.

Comment: @SethJ So why does the pronunciation change with different words in the video Hacham Gabriel linked to?

Comment: @Ariel, it sounds right to me.

Comment: @Ariel however, listening to the rest, it sounds like he loses some of his accent midway through WeHayah Im Shamoa', but it (mostly) comes back during Wayomer. Sisith sounds like Sisit, to me.

Comment: (I guess it takes a lot of concentration. I often wonder why some people are inconsistent with their Oys, and a pet peeve of mine is when people close their lips before finishing an open syllable, which makes it sound like they've added an M to the end of the word. Same phenomenon, I'd guess. Personal imperfection audible even when trying to be proper.)

Comment: @Ariel, check out http://www.dailyhalacha.com/ for abundant examples, especially now with discussions about the Misvot for Pesah and selling Hames.

Comment: @SethJ great call, I was thinkning of bringing Harav Mansour Shalit"a Mori HaMuvhak, but I didn't want to bring a whole 50 minute Shuir to prove the "s".

Comment: @HachamGabriel In the first video you link to around 0:34 he mispronounces the word ודברת as mil'eil thereby changing its tense from future to past. That is a correctable mistake when leining IMO. See also  http://www.ou.org/torah/tt/5762/vayeshev62/dav.htm

Comment: @DoubleAA what exactly is your point?

Comment: @HachamGabriel You said that was Keriat Shema the way you pronounce it, and I'm saying I hope you don't make that same mistake in your pronunciation. I wouldn't want you saying the wrong thing in your Keriat Shema.

Comment: @DoubleAA Ashrecha!!